# CSS Gradient to plain background

Tags: css

I have a button and I've added a gradient to it.

Here is the code:

```
.mybutton {
    background: #258dc8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #258dc8 0%, #258dc8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#258dc8), color-stop(100%,#258dc8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #258dc8 0%,#258dc8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #258dc8 0%,#258dc8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #258dc8 0%,#258dc8 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #258dc8 0%,#258dc8 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#258dc8', endColorstr='#258dc8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

My problem is that in the hover state I want to get rid of the gradient and just have a plain background color.

```
.mybutton:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

For some reason this is not working as it's not getting rid of the gradient.
The only way I've been able to change the gradient is by adding another gradient.

Is there a way to disable the gradient?

I've also tried `background: none;` but this didn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradients are [image values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients), so setting `background-color` alone won't affect your gradient. You'll specifically want to override the `background-image` property (as well as `filter` while you're at it):

```
.mybutton:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;
}
```

If you use the shorthand `background: none`, you're setting *both* the color and the image (`none` maps to `background-image` and omitting a color sets that to `transparent`), so you'll get a transparent background instead.

Of course, you could use the shorthand to declare just the color instead, and the image will implicitly be `none`:

```
.mybutton:hover {
    background: #333333;
    filter: none;
}
```